# Apply Sequence based on unique_id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
unique_id   col_id   val_id
1           100      a
1           101      b
1           102      c
1           103      d

2           106      a
2           106      b
2           104      c
2           103      d
```

I want to use a sequence to assign it for each unique_id.

I wrote the following which doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT
    my_seq.NEXTVAL over
(
    PARTITION BY a.unique_id ORDER by a.unique_id) AS rec_i,
     a.* FROM table1
a;
```

The output would be:

```
unique_id   col_id   val_id   rec_i
1           100      a        123
1           101      b        123
1           102      c        123
1           103      d        123

2           106      a        124
2           106      b        124
2           104      c        124
2           103      d        124
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Why is the unique_id column not good enough to use as the rec_i?

Comment: unique_id is coming from the source table. I need to use my sequence which is already used in my destination table. I need to insert these rows to my destination table.

Comment: unique_id is a badly named column, btw; the values in that column aren't unique! It would be difficult to assign a sequence to the rows as they are, because <seq>.nextval is **not** an analytic function, which is what you're trying to use it for. You could perhaps use a combination of the row_number() analytic function to assign the <seq>.nextval to the first row in each group, and then use the first_value() analytic function to assign the values to the remaining rows in each group.

Comment: This makes sense. Do you have SQL query in mind to do it?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could turn your question into a test case, with create table statements for your destination and source tables, create sequence statement, etc, along with the output you expect to see in the output table. Bonus points if you also set up the test case in  [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18)

Comment: Given that there seems to be a 1:1 correlation between `unique_id` and your proposed `rec_i` what exactly is the benefit of `rec_i`?

Comment: I need this to insert in my destination table. rec_i is my sequence for destination table.

Comment: Does it actually matter if rec_i is the same as unique_id?

Comment: yes, rec_i cannot be same unique_id. It should be based on the existing sequence i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-- data preparation
create table tt_table (unique_id   number, col_id   number, val_id varchar2(1));

insert into tt_table values(1,100,'a');
insert into tt_table values(1,101,'b');
insert into tt_table values(1,102,'c');
insert into tt_table values(1,103,'d');

insert into tt_table values(2,106,'a');
insert into tt_table values(2,104,'b');
insert into tt_table values(2,103,'c');
insert into tt_table values(2,103,'d');



-- creating function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_SEQ RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
    RETURN TEJASH_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END GET_SEQ;
/


--
-- actual query
--
WITH T2 AS (
    SELECT /*+ materialize */
        UNIQUE_ID,
        GET_SEQ   SEQ_VALUE
    FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                UNIQUE_ID
            FROM
                TT_TABLE
        ) T2IN
)
SELECT
    T1.UNIQUE_ID,
    T1.COL_ID,
    T1.VAL_ID,
    T2.SEQ_VALUE
FROM
    TT_TABLE T1,
    T2
WHERE
    T1.UNIQUE_ID = T2.UNIQUE_ID
ORDER BY
    T1.UNIQUE_ID;
```

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Great, let me test it. Are you on Skype?

Comment: Test it and let me know if it worked for you correctly?
Share me your Skype ID, I will ping you.

Comment: Here - https://onetimesecret.com/secret/jpf02baag4usyxagpqp2bn3q7c8747c